# Trouble setting UIImageView.image on custom class from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have a custom class A that is a subclass of `UIView` which essentially manages a `UIScrollView` that fits the size of the view and the contains an `UIImageView` that fills that scrollView.

I am having trouble setting the imageView.image of the custom class:

Here's the class

```
#import "BackgroundPickerView.h"

@implementation BackgroundPickerView

@synthesize scrollView;
@synthesize imageView;
@synthesize actionButton;

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    return self;
}

-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    //[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
      //                                       selector:@selector(changeImage)
        //                                         name:@"ImageChangeNotification"
          //                                     object:nil];

    //Here's where we add custom subviews
    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    actionButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];

    [scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 321, 115)];
    [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 321, 115)];
    [actionButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 115)];

    scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0;
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 200);//imageView.image.size; 

    [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    [self addSubview:scrollView];
}

-(void)storeImage:(UIImage *)image
{   
    self.imageView.image = image;
}

-(void)changeImage
{
    [self.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"random.png"]];
}
```

From my other class B where I receive the image I have tried using NSNotification and a simple setter method to try setting the **imageView** property of the class object, but cannot seem to set the imageView.image. I have tried using

`instance.imageView.image = myImageToSet`

```
//Setter
[instance storeImage:myImageToSet];
```

in class B but am having no success

Comment: try doing  [ [alloc] init] in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`& if  its subclass of UIView then do [[alloc ]init] in init method or awakeFromNib if you are doing nib loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, the initialisation of subviews in `layoutSubviews` not the best way, better u initialise them in the `init` method, because `layoutSubviews` may call multiple times to layout the subviews, if u place the initialisation code in the `layoutSubviews` there might be may subviews. in `layoutSubviews` u only set the `frame` of the subviews.

and u can do like below,

```
 #import "BackgroundPickerView.h" 
 @implementation CustomViewA

 //Edit change below 

 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
  {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self)
    {
     [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
   [self commonInit];
}

 - (void)commonInit
 {
   _scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
   _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
   _actionButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];

   _scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
   _scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
   _scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0;

   [_scrollView addSubview:_imageView];
   [self addSubview:_scrollView];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
 {
   [super layoutSubviews];
   [_scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 321, 115)];
   [_imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 321, 115)];
   [_actionButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 115)];

   _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 200);
 }

 -(void)storeImage:(UIImage *)image
 {
    self.imageView.image = image;
 }

 -(void)changeImage
 {
   [self.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"random.png"]];
 }
```

`synthesise` is optional
and in `BackgroundPickerView.h` file it is something like below

```
 @interface BackgroundPickerView : UIView
 @property (nonatomic, strong) UIScrollView *scrollView;
 @property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView  *imageView;
 @property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton     *actionButton;

 -(void)storeImage:(UIImage *)image;
 -(void)changeImage;
```

for image u check it it should work, check the image is present or not,

**Edit**
For the image, in `controller` for example,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   _viewA = [[BackgroundPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
   [self.view addSubview:_viewA];
 }

 //for testing 
 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [_viewA storeImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"]]; //hear do this
 }
```

Comment: Great answer should've thought about that. Ill try that now.

Comment: Im still not able to set the image being set when calling, from the other controller, `instance.imageView.image = myImage;`

Comment: check the image. it should work check, the edited answer

Comment: my `instance` is actually a storyboard referenced object. It's a UIView with its class set to BackgroundPickerView. Testing the issue now

Comment: ok then u are initialising the view in storyboard, i will edit the answer wait